# Binding DBCONTEXT to gridview via boundfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I have a gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="ParentSelect" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="ParentSelect_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="ParentSelect_RowCreated" emptydatatext="Please Submit A Clip. C'mon dude." ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="600" CssClass= "table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
<HeaderStyle BorderColor="Black"   />
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField ="dbContext.Mains.VideoUrl" HeaderText="Title" Visible="false" />
</Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
```

and i have binded my DBCONTEXT:

```
protected void LoadGrid()
{
    ParentSelect.DataSource = dbContext.Mains.ToList(); 
    ParentSelect.DataBind();
}
```

I want to display data from the database on my gridview via a BoundField. How can I accomplish this? 
Please and thank you.

Comment: call this `LoadGrid()` method on `Page_Load`

Comment: If I do this it displays the column names from the database which is not what I want. I want to mask the column names in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple as this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField ="VideoUrl" HeaderText="Title" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @NKN Why this is not an answer?

Comment: It can be an answer, if you consider adding some explanation to it. Posting just a piece of code, should be avoided according to SO.

Comment: @NKN link-only answers should be avoided. From SO Help Center: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better". Not all answers need further explanations.